# search through array of strings for string match from another array php

Tags: php

I have an issue that I have two txt files, where one contains a values of what to search and second contains info from where I need to find text line which contains info from first txt file.
1. txt file looks like this:

```html
1461527867
29012520
2220097051
2596180150
29012516
2596180152
29012514
```

2. txt file looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.4.3 (797 thorn-02.openstreetmap.org)" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/">
 <bounds minlat="56.7042000" minlon="21.5789000" maxlat="56.7340000" maxlon="21.6328000"/>
 <node id="29012520" visible="true" version="2" changeset="3098893" timestamp="2009-11-12T15:12:59Z" user="Abuls" uid="14113" lat="56.7183050" lon="21.6051939"/>
 <node id="29012518" visible="true" version="2" changeset="3098893" timestamp="2009-11-12T15:12:59Z" user="Abuls" uid="14113" lat="56.7184563" lon="21.6161018"/>
 <node id="29012516" visible="true" version="2" changeset="3100827" timestamp="2009-11-12T19:23:00Z" user="Abuls" uid="14113" lat="56.7180402" lon="21.6222515"/>
 <node id="29012514" visible="true" version="2" changeset="3100827" timestamp="2009-11-12T19:23:00Z" user="Abuls" uid="14113" lat="56.7191410" lon="21.6324709"/>
```

So I need to find in 2. txt all lines where nod id is equal with nummber given in 1. txt file and than I need to cut out the latitude and longitude values of this searched string line.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: That is the thing that I have tried out so many code options that I can't understand what am I doing anymore - all what I have found so far is that there are no problems to compare arrays if other array contain exact the same value you are searching fore. but in this case I'm searching for case where array value is partly containing a value I'm searching

Comment: So basically, if any line from 1.txt is found in the node id of 2.txt then retrieve corresponding latitude and longitude values. Right?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it's working for you.

Comment: Thank you all for help! Now I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
$handle = fopen("1.txt", "r");

$xml = simplexml_load_file("2.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

if ($handle) {

    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        foreach ($xml as $key => $value) {

            if ($value['id'] == trim($line)) {

                echo "id: " . $value['id'] . " Lat => " . $value['lat'] . " " . "lon => " . $value['lon'] . "</br>";
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);

} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

**Output**

```
id: 29012520 Lat => 56.7183050 lon => 21.6051939
id: 29012516 Lat => 56.7180402 lon => 21.6222515
id: 29012514 Lat => 56.7191410 lon => 21.6324709
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a little code to get you started.

```
// Step 1: Need to load the files:
// put the paths to your files in these two variables
$textFile = 'locations.txt';
$xmlFilePath = 'data.xml';

$idHandle = fopen($textFile, 'r');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($xmlFilePath);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Step 2: getting each line in the text file
while ($id = fgets($idHandle)) {
  $id = (int) $id;
  // Step 3: selecting all the nodes that have ids matching 
  // the id in the text file
  $query = "//node[@id={$id}]";
  $list = $xpath->evaluate($query);

  foreach ($list as $node) {
    echo "Node: {$id}, Latitude: " . $node->getAttribute('lat') 
      . ", " .  "Longitude: " . $node->getAttribute('lon') . "\n"; 
  }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Node: 29012520, Latitude: 56.7183050, Longitude: 21.6051939
Node: 29012516, Latitude: 56.7180402, Longitude: 21.6222515
Node: 29012514, Latitude: 56.7191410, Longitude: 21.6324709
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `SimpleXMLElement`, `foreach`, `file_get_contents`, and `preg_split` to get the result you desire. Here is what is meant:

```
    <?php
        // GET THE CONTENTS OF THE TEXT FILE CONTAINING IDS
        // AND BUNDLE IT INTO A VARIABLE FOR LATER USE.
        $txtFileContent = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/ids.txt");

        // CONVERT THE CONTENTS OF THE TEXT FILE TO AN ARRAY
        $arrTextData    = preg_split("#[\n\r]#", $txtFileContent);


        // CREATE A SIMPLE XML ELEMENT USING THE XML FILE.
        $sXML           = new SimpleXMLElement(__DIR__ . "/xml_file_name.xml", 0, true);

        // LOOP THROUGH ALL THE ELEMENTS IN THE CHILDREN LIST
        // AND TRY TO MATCH EACH ELEMENT WITH EACH KEY ON THE $arrTextData ARRAY.
        // THIS WOULD IMPLY A NESTED LOOP... ALSO BUILD AN ARRAY OF
        // MATCHED-ELEMENTS WITH THE UNIQUE ID AS THE KEY IN THE PROCESS.
        $arrMatchedElements = array();

        foreach($sXML->children() as $nodeKey=>$nodeData){
            /**@var SimpleXMLElement $nodeData */
            foreach($arrTextData as $iKey=>$ID){
                if($ID == $nodeData->attributes()->id){
                    $arrMatchedElements[$ID]    = $nodeData->attributes();
                }
            }
        }

        var_dump($arrMatchedElements);
        // THE var_dump(...) PRODUCES...            
        array (size=3)
          29012520 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
              public '@attributes' => 
                array (size=9)
                  'id' => string '29012520' (length=8)
                  'visible' => string 'true' (length=4)
                  'version' => string '2' (length=1)
                  'changeset' => string '3098893' (length=7)
                  'timestamp' => string '2009-11-12T15:12:59Z' (length=20)
                  'user' => string 'Abuls' (length=5)
                  'uid' => string '14113' (length=5)
                  'lat' => string '56.7183050' (length=10)
                  'lon' => string '21.6051939' (length=10)
          29012516 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
              public '@attributes' => 
                array (size=9)
                  'id' => string '29012516' (length=8)
                  'visible' => string 'true' (length=4)
                  'version' => string '2' (length=1)
                  'changeset' => string '3100827' (length=7)
                  'timestamp' => string '2009-11-12T19:23:00Z' (length=20)
                  'user' => string 'Abuls' (length=5)
                  'uid' => string '14113' (length=5)
                  'lat' => string '56.7180402' (length=10)
                  'lon' => string '21.6222515' (length=10)
          29012514 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[8]
              public '@attributes' => 
                array (size=9)
                  'id' => string '29012514' (length=8)
                  'visible' => string 'true' (length=4)
                  'version' => string '2' (length=1)
                  'changeset' => string '3100827' (length=7)
                  'timestamp' => string '2009-11-12T19:23:00Z' (length=20)
                  'user' => string 'Abuls' (length=5)
                  'uid' => string '14113' (length=5)
                  'lat' => string '56.7191410' (length=10)
                  'lon' => string '21.6324709' (length=10)
```

You can also make this more Object Oriented like so:

```
    <?php   
        // GET THE CONTENTS OF THE TEXT FILE CONTAINING IDS
        // AND BUNDLE IT INTO A VARIABLE FOR LATER USE. 
        $txtFileContent = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/ids.txt");

        // CONVERT THE CONTENTS OF THE TEXT-FILE TO AN ARRAY
        $arrTextData    = preg_split("#[\n\r]#", $txtFileContent);

        // CREATE A SIMPLE XML ELEMENT USING THE XML FILE.
        $sXML           = new SimpleXMLElement(__DIR__ . "/xml_file_name.xml", 0, true);

        // LOOP THROUGH ALL THE ELEMENTS IN THE CHILDREN LIST
        // AND TRY TO MATCH EACH ELEMENT WITH EACH KEY ON THE $arrTextData ARRAY.
        // THIS WOULD IMPLY A NESTED LOOP... ALSO BUILD A MATCHED-ELEMENTS
        // ARRAY IN THE PROCESS.
        $arrMatchedElements = array();

        foreach($sXML->children() as $nodeKey=>$nodeData){
            /**@var SimpleXMLElement $nodeData */
            foreach($arrTextData as $iKey=>$ID){
                if($ID == $nodeData->attributes()->id){
                    $tempPropsObj               = new stdClass();
                    $tempPropsObj->id           = $nodeData->attributes()
                            ->id->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->lon          = $nodeData->attributes()->lon->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->lat          = $nodeData->attributes()->lon->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->uid          = $nodeData->attributes()->uid->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->user         = $nodeData->attributes()->user->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->timestamp    = $nodeData->attributes()->timestamp->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->changeset    = $nodeData->attributes()->changeset->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->version      = $nodeData->attributes()->version->__toString();
                    $tempPropsObj->visible      = $nodeData->attributes()->visible->__toString();
                    $arrMatchedElements[$ID]    = $tempPropsObj;
                }
            }
        }

        var_dump($arrMatchedElements);
        // DISPLAYS...
        array (size=3)
          29012520 => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              public 'id' => string '29012520' (length=8)
              public 'lon' => string '21.6051939' (length=10)
              public 'lat' => string '21.6051939' (length=10)
              public 'uid' => string '14113' (length=5)
              public 'user' => string 'Abuls' (length=5)
              public 'timestamp' => string '2009-11-12T15:12:59Z' (length=20)
              public 'changeset' => string '3098893' (length=7)
              public 'version' => string '2' (length=1)
              public 'visible' => string 'true' (length=4)
          29012516 => 
            object(stdClass)[5]
              public 'id' => string '29012516' (length=8)
              public 'lon' => string '21.6222515' (length=10)
              public 'lat' => string '21.6222515' (length=10)
              public 'uid' => string '14113' (length=5)
              public 'user' => string 'Abuls' (length=5)
              public 'timestamp' => string '2009-11-12T19:23:00Z' (length=20)
              public 'changeset' => string '3100827' (length=7)
              public 'version' => string '2' (length=1)
              public 'visible' => string 'true' (length=4)
          29012514 => 
            object(stdClass)[8]
              public 'id' => string '29012514' (length=8)
              public 'lon' => string '21.6324709' (length=10)
              public 'lat' => string '21.6324709' (length=10)
              public 'uid' => string '14113' (length=5)
              public 'user' => string 'Abuls' (length=5)
              public 'timestamp' => string '2009-11-12T19:23:00Z' (length=20)
              public 'changeset' => string '3100827' (length=7)
              public 'version' => string '2' (length=1)
              public 'visible' => string 'true' (length=4)
```

Hope this helps a bit.... GOOD LUCK ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all in your example your XML code has no ending tag `</osm>`, which probably was only a mistake when copy paste.

Because you have an XML file, you don't need to parse it by yourself, PHP offers a lot of functions to do that for you.

As far as I know, there is no possibility to check if the value of a XML is equal to another value, so you have to check it in two loops, as you can see in my example below.

```
<?php
//Read the id's
$ids = file("txt.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

//Read the XML file
$xmlContent = file_get_contents("txt.xml");

//Convert XML file to an object
$xmlObjects = simplexml_load_string($xmlContent);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    foreach ($xmlObjects->node as $node) {

        //Check if id's are equal
        if ($node["id"] == $id) {
            echo "ID: ".$id;
            echo " Latitude: ".$node["lat"];
            echo " Longidtude ".$node["lon"];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ID: 29012520 Latitude: 56.7183050 Longidtude 21.6051939
ID: 29012516 Latitude: 56.7180402 Longidtude 21.6222515
ID: 29012514 Latitude: 56.7191410 Longidtude 21.6324709
```